# Python for every sequence of random sample generated also include an individual ID

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to program a Lotto simulator, where the code generates 6 random unique numbers out of 45 for about 1000 players where each player has a unique ID. I want to place it into an array that looks like this:

```
lotto[0...n-1][0...5]
```

Where [0...n-1] contains the players ID, and [0...5] their unique 6 game numbers.

So it should look something like this when printed

```
lotto[1][32, 34, 24, 13, 20, 8]
lotto[2][1, 27, 4, 41, 33, 17]
...
lotto[1000][6, 12, 39, 16, 45, 3]
```

What is the best way of doing something like this without actually merging the two arrays together?

As later on I want to use a merge-sort algorithm to then numerically order the game numbers for each player so it would look something like this without the players ID interfering with the game numbers.

```
lotto[1][8, 13, 20, 24, 32, 34]
lotto[2][1, 4, 17, 27, 33, 41]
```

So far I've got:

```
playerID = list(range(1, 1001)) 
playerNum = random.sample(range(1, 45), 6)
print(playerID + playerNum)
```

But that just prints and joins:

```
[1, 2, 3, ..., 1000, 32, 5, 19, 27, 6, 22]
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

n_players = 1000
lotto = [random.sample(range(1, 45), 6) for _ in range(n_players)]
```

OR

```
import random

n_players = 1000
tup = tuple(range(1, 45))
lotto = []
for _ in range(n_players):
    lotto.append(random.sample(tup, 6))
```